# How can I get Cloudfront to cache the resulting content of a Rails redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an endpoint in my Rails app where a model id and a couple other parameters form the URL. From there, I look up that model in the DB, and redirect to an image stored on Amazon S3.

Cloudfront is ALWAYS in front of this url, and I really want it to cache the image. Right now, it's caching the redirect, which means it's serving straight from the S3 bucket which is not as efficient.

What can I do? Is there a header I can add to tell Cloudfront to cache the result? Or is there a way I can use Rack::Rewrite but still have access to my ActiveRecord models?

Comment: There is *nothing* you can do to get CloudFront to cache the content of the target location instead of just caching the redirect response itself.  Following redirects is a responsibility of the user agent (browser).

Comment: So if following redirects is out of the question, then along with the Rack::Rewrite + ActiveRecord question, is there any creative way to efficiently download the resulting file and serve it up directly? Like redirecting a file stream? It seems awkwardly slow to require my web server to download and upload a file instead of redirecting, but I can't think of a more clever solution.

Comment: Well, if your path hierarchy permits it, you can map certain path patterns in cloudfront to go directly to S3 as a secondary origin... or just set up a second Cloudfront distro pointing straight to the bucket.

Comment: So the order would be Cloudfront A -> Rails -> Cloudfront B -> AWS. It's true it would stop at Cloudfront B and serve more efficiently THERE, but I'm still hitting my Rails server and generating the redirection rule for every single request, right?

Comment: I've been trying downloading the data and immediately serving it back up, but it feels like a pretty hacky solution. Even if I manually visit all of the URLs to fill the Cloudfront cache, I'm only filling it in my location. As soon as someone visits from another hemisphere, it takes 5 seconds to load a page of 10 images.

It sounds like my options are either: serve everything slowly through S3, or take forever to fill the caches and have a lot of users experience REALLY slow loads. Also, to clarify the comment about path hierarchy, there are no patterns to be mapped so that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the only solution that worked was to change the original S3 URL's. I moved all the logic that computed the URL by model id and other parameters like I described to the S3 image generation. That way my frontend could still generate these urls. Then I set up a Cloudfront URL mapped to the S3 bucket itself and pointed my app to that for image urls.